# Not able to use internet on Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, dual-boot, internet

After dual booting Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10 first problem I faced was that I was unable to connect to the Internet in Ubuntu. Then I restarted my computer to windows to see that the connection is perfectly fine. So again I restarted to Ubuntu. Now it was able to connect to the Internet. But after that and till now Windows is unable to connect to the Internet. I use an ethernet cable to connect to the Internet which is connected to our Institutes LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check on your **LAN drivers**  in windows **internet options** settings.
open the command prompt with adminstrator privileges and run `msinfo32`